# What tense should this sentence be phrased in based on the accompanying action which has taken place?

Tags: tenses

In the following scenario you can buy/sell offices in different cities, so say the user purchases an office in London, then the user sells it and we wish to show the user a message that the sale has taken place, should it be phrased like:

this,

> You sold your Office which ***is*** situated in London for  495,000.

or

> You sold your Office which ***was*** situated in London for  495,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally phrased as something like:
"Your London office (or office in London) has just sold for $495,000".
This is because of aspect in reference to past tense.

Comment: I like the move here to separate "London for 495,000."

Answer (score 0):

Both the versions are possible, however with different focusses. The first one looks at the office as still existing. The second one as admitting of no link of the office to  speaker's present.